# Why CounterService fails to count the times a method was invoked?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-boot-actuator

I am using `spring AOP` and spring boot `CounterService` to record the times of invocation for a specific method. Each time I visit the target url, the countServiceInvoke would be executed, but the output metrics value will always be `1`. `"gauge.servo.string_com.yirendai.oss.environment.admin.controller.restcontrollertest.test()": 1`.

I want to know why this counter failed? Thanks. The util class is like bellow:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ServiceMonitor {
  @Autowired
  private CounterService counterService;

  @Before("execution(* com.yirendai.oss.environment.admin.controller.*.*(..))")
  public void countServiceInvoke(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" + joinPoint.getSignature());
    counterService.increment(joinPoint.getSignature() + "");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have read the source code of the implemented class of CounterService, key should be started with `"meter."` in order to correctly counted.

```
private void incrementInternal(String name, long value) {
        String strippedName = stripMetricName(name);

        if (name.startsWith("status.")) {
            // drop this metric since we are capturing it already with
            // ServoHandlerInterceptor,
            // and we are able to glean more information like exceptionType from that
            // mechanism than what
            // boot provides us
        }
        else if (name.startsWith("meter.")) {
            BasicCounter counter = counters.get(strippedName);
            if (counter == null) {
                counter = new BasicCounter(MonitorConfig.builder(strippedName).build());
                counters.put(strippedName, counter);
                registry.register(counter);
            }
            counter.increment(value);
        }
        else {
            LongGauge gauge = longGauges.get(strippedName);
            if (gauge == null) {
                gauge = new LongGauge(MonitorConfig.builder(strippedName).build());
                longGauges.put(strippedName, gauge);
                registry.register(gauge);
            }
            gauge.set(value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I hit this problem as well.  Wonder why it doesn't seem to be documented.  Thanks for investigating.